# Changed Target name in Xcode now it runs a black screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

So I changed the name of my target in xcode for some stupid reason, then changed it back immediately and my application won't run. The simulator just displays a black screen.

This is stressing me alot. Willing to try anything at this point

Comment: It's a feature, not a bug! :D

Comment: if it helps, I can no longer find the .app files on my mac

Comment: ok so how do I run find my app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you say "yes" when it prompted you to allow snapshots?

If so, you can try to revert this change by going to File > Restore Snapshot.

**Edit**

Bummer about the "no" answer...

Based on your comments though, it's possible that your schemes may be messed up. Try this:

1) Click on the project name drop-down (to the right of stop button)

2) Click on "Manage Schemes"

3) Select all schemes and press delete

4) Click on "autocreate schemes now" at the top right

5) Clean, then try building and running again

Comment: I think I said no, for another extremely poor decision making moment

Comment: Yeah... you really should always say "yes" to this... try the suggestion by @Fernando Mazzon, which may work...

Comment: worked. Some issues arose when it autocreated new schemes (auto-created some code in my delegate, but I got rid of it. Thank you very much. +1.

Answer (score 2):

Delete app, clean, reopen xCode. yes, xCode is dumb sometimes

Comment: I like this suggestion better than mine. Yes, Xcode hates me too! :D

Comment: tried this, didn't work. Even after I rebuild there is no .app file on the disk? So it keeps trying to build to no product/target

Comment: check the build log (last icon on the left pane, open up Build XYZ XYZ), check on the bottom for the Link call to see where the file should be located... Might have clues

Comment: Ok so I need a a new target I think?